# jQuery LocalScroll breaks on update from 1.3.2 to 1.4.4

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging, scroll

I'm using Ariel Flesler's awesome plugins [ScrollTo](http://flesler.blogspot.com/search/label/jQuery.ScrollTo) & [LocalScroll](http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jquerylocalscroll-10.html) on a project.

I've copied the code from one project (where it is working perfectly to another).  It's not working on the new project and after a bit of debug I discovered that it's the jQuery version.

The older project is on 1.3.2 and the newer is on 1.4.4.  Firebug's script debug is reporting the following error:

```
Break on Error
target is undefined
```

Lines 2 and 3 of the following code are the reason for the error being thrown:

```
// Scrolling function by Ariel Flesler http://flesler.webs.com/jQuery.LocalScroll/
jQuery(function( $ ){

    var target = $().get(0);

    target.scrollLeft = target.scrollTop = 0;

    var $last = $([]);

    $('#main-contain').localScroll({
        axis:'y',
        queue:true,
        duration:1000,
        hash:true,
        lazy:true,
        offset: { left:0, top:-100 },
        onBefore:function( e, anchor, $target ){
            $last.removeClass('scrolling');
            $last = $(this).addClass('scrolling');
        },
        onAfter:function( anchor ){
            $last.removeClass('scrolling');
        }
    });
});
```

**Any ideas why the change from jQuery 1.3.2 to jQuery 1.4.4?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var target = $().get(0);
```

This is an empty jQuery object.

for some reason, `.get(0);` is OK in jQuery 1.3.2, but does not work in jQuery 1.4.4.  The solution is:

```
var target = $().get();  // note the lack of 0
```

Comment: Ok, good start.  Now why does that same object work with no problem in 1.3.2 ... need to know that if I'm going to fix it.

Comment: As far as I know it might have been somekind of bug.
Depending on WHAT you want to scroll to 0 you should use that name. If it's your document you could use `$(document)` but if you're using another element you should put it's name, id or class there.